# Can WebView2 be used inside a Dll?

Tags: dll, webview2

Tested the WebView2GettingStarted project. Worked fine. Created a MFC Dll and copied the HelloWebView.cpp file and added it to the Dll project. Renamed WinMain to something else. Installed the packages from NuGet.

When the Dll is compiled, I get the error:

Error   C2440   'specialization': cannot convert from 'void (__stdcall *)(HANDLE) noexcept' to 'unknown-type'   WebView2Dll c:\temp\webview2dll\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.230202.1\include\wil\resource.h    2550

Any suggestions on an option setting or something else to fix the problem?

I modified WINAPI_FAMILY to WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP and got rid of that problem but other parameters (e.g. IDCompositionDevice)were not being defined.

Comment: It can be used from within a DLL. It sounds like the issue is that you are using WIL headers which depend on types and macros that aren't defined in your project. Like you need to #include some other Windows headers before you #include the WIL headers

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The WIL headers are the last includes after all the Windows includes. The WIL headers were added to the framework.h file which was created when the DLL project was created.